# Permutation Inequality relating to Exponential determinant

Tags: inequality, permutations

Let $x_1 < \cdots < x_n$ and $y_1 < \cdots < y_n$.

Prove that $\det(e^{x_iy_j}) > 0$.

Expanding out the determinant shows that it suffices to prove:

$$\sum_{even} \sum x_iy_{\sigma{(i)}} > \sum_{odd} \sum x_i y_{\sigma{(i)}}$$
Which is kinda like a generalized rearrangement inequality, but I'm not quite sure how to finish it.

Reading the solutions to "positivity of the determinant" answers my original question, but I would like to see if it is possible to have a proof of the above inequality.

Comment: If the $x_j$ and $y_j$ are numbers, then $\det(e^{x_iy_j}) = e^{x_iy_j}$ because it's just a number. Also, your inequality is wrong. Where is $e$?

Comment: @amsmath: What is probably meant is the determinant of the square matrix with the entries $(e^{x_i y_j})_{i,j}$. – (In that case it is a duplicate.)

Comment: @MartinR That's meant for sure. I just wanted to make OP aware of certain inaccuracies that may lead to confusion. Actually, I don't like this behavior. OP wants something from us, not conversely. So, they should take some time in order to not waste *our* time for interpretating the question.